# snakemake missing output exception after job completed

Tags: wildcard, missing-data, snakemake

I'm running DASTool via snakemake, and for some reason, though I get the output bins, the following error crops us. While it's a minor annoyance since I have the output, it kills my snakemake run immediately after. The snakefile looks like this:

```
rule DAS_Tool:
    input:
            da1="{datadir}/{mapper}_{reads}_{sample}/dastool_output/{sample}_metabat.scaffolds2bin.tsv",
            da2="{datadir}/{mapper}_{reads}_{sample}/dastool_output/{sample}_maxbin.scaffolds2bin.tsv",
            da3="{datadir}/{sample}.fna",
            db=config["dastool_database"]
    threads:config["threads"]
    conda:"binning.yml"
    output:
            daout=directory("{datadir}/{mapper}_{reads}_{sample}/dastool_output/{sample}")
    shell:
            """
            date
            DAS_Tool -i {input.da1},{input.da2} -c {input.da3} -o {output.daout} --search_engine diamond -l maxbin2,metabat2 --write_bins 1 --write_bin_evals 1 --threads {threads} --db_directory {input.db} --create_plots 1 &&\
            2> >(tee {log}.stderr) > >(tee {log}.stdout)
            touch das_tool.done
            date
```

The error reads as such:

```
Waiting at most 120 seconds for missing files.
MissingOutputException in line 277 of /mnt/lscratch/users/sbusi/ONT/cedric_ont_basecalling/Binning/metaspades_binning_snakefile:
Job completed successfully, but some output files are missing. Missing files after 120 seconds:
/scratch/users/sbusi/ONT/cedric_ont_basecalling/Binning/bwa_sr_metaspades/dastool_output/metaspades
This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait.
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

What other files may be missing that it's terminating the job? I've tried the --latency-wait option upto 900 seconds, but no luck yet.

Thank you!

EDIT: based on Gajapathy's comment, I've edited the file to look so:

```
rule DAS_Tool:
    input:
            da1="{datadir}/{mapper}_{reads}_{sample}/dastool_output/{sample}_metabat.scaffolds2bin.tsv",
            da2="{datadir}/{mapper}_{reads}_{sample}/dastool_output/{sample}_maxbin.scaffolds2bin.tsv",
            da3="{datadir}/{sample}.fna",
            db=config["dastool_database"]
    threads:config["threads"]
    conda:"/home/users/sbusi/apps/environments/base.yml"
    params:
            basename="{datadir}/{mapper}_{reads}_{sample}/dastool_output/{sample}"
    output:
            daout=directory("{datadir}/{mapper}_{reads}_{sample}/dastool_output/{sample}_DASTool_bins"),
            dafile="{datadir}/{mapper}_{reads}_{sample}/dastool_output/{sample}_proteins.faa",
            damfile=touch("{datadir}/{mapper}_{reads}_{sample}_das_tool.done")
    shell:
            """
            date
            DAS_Tool -i {input.da1},{input.da2} -c {input.da3} -o {params.basename} --search_engine diamond -l maxbin2,metabat2 --write_bins 1 --write_bin_evals 1 --threads {threads} --db_directory {input.db} --create_plots 1 &&\
            2> >(tee {log}.stderr) > >(tee {log}.stdout)
            touch {output.damfile}
            date
            """
```

It works!! thank you @Gajapathy!

Comment: What is the output of `pwd` if you change your working directory to where your output is? I am guessing there is a difference between that path and the one snakemake looks for.

Comment: This is where the root folder for the output is: ```/scratch/users/sbusi/ONT/cedric_ont_basecalling/Binning/mmi_lr_metaspades```

And this is where the snakefile output is directing to:
```
/scratch/users/sbusi/ONT/cedric_ont_basecalling/Binning/mmi_lr_metaspades/dastool_output/metaspades```

Comment: I'm also running MetaBAT/MaxBin/DAStool via Snakemake, and I'm encountering similar errors at the MaxBin part of the pipeline - would you be willing to share your Snakemake rule(s) for creating your "{sample}_maxbin.scaffolds2bin.tsv" file?

Comment: @ZoeyRW: the rule is too long to post here. Would you mind emailing me: it's `susheel.busi at-the-rate-of uni.lu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [DAS_Tool's doc](https://github.com/cmks/DAS_Tool), `-o` is to define basename of output files; not output folder.

```
   -o, --outputbasename       Basename of output files.
```

So a generic simplified rule would look like

```
rule DAS_Tool:
    output: 'path/to/outdir/basename_proteins.faa`
    params: basename = 'path/to/outdir/basename'
    shell: "DAS_Tool .... -o {params.basename} ...."
```

If you don't want to hardcode basename in `params`, you could use python's lambda magic to get it from output files in param.

Comment: Based on your comment, I'm trying an updated version, I'm going to edit the original post since it's a little messy to post here. Still getting the error though. Thank you!

update: it WORKS.. thank you very much!!